# Solving complicated recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relation

This question is based on the solution to topcoder SRM-620 [question](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13161&rd=15853&rm=322142&cr=23265646):

```
bool solve(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a == c && b == d)
        return true;
    if(a > c || b > d)
        return false;
    return solve(a+b,b,c,d)||solve(a,b+a,c,d);
}
```

The time complexity is given by the recurrence formula

$$
T(a,b,c,d) = 
\begin{cases}
c_1,         & \text{$a=c$ and $b=d$}, \\
c_2,         & \text{$a>c$ or $b>d$}, \\
T(a+b,b,c,d) + T(a,b+a,c,d) +c_3,      & \text{otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
$$

How do I transform this to closed form if possible?

Comment: I suggest that you run your algorithm the other way around - subtract c from d or vice versa.

Comment: Do you want a closed form or just an estimate?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Note that in your algorithm, `solve` does sometimes take four and sometimes two parameters.

Comment: @Raphael I want to analysis the complexity of it, but stuck at the transform the recurrence formula to closed form

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if a closed form is not possible, an estimate is ok

Comment: If $a = b = 1$ then `solve` runs once for each pair $(x, y)$ with $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ and $x < c, y < d$. I think.